# How to deploy Qt imageformats plugins on Android

Tags: android, qt, plugins, qml, qt5.9

I'm trying to get image format plugins working on Android.

My plan is to build this [APNG](https://github.com/Skycoder42/qapng) image format plugin, which closely follows the style of the official Qt extra [image format plugins](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimageformats-index.html). The answer to my problem will be the same for these too.

On desktop (windows) it works. So long as you put the plugin DLL into a `imageformats` subdirectory like this:

```
myapp/<all my binaries>
imageformats/qapng.dll
```

But on Android, it's another story;

First idea was to put `libqapng.so` into `libs` so that `qtcreator` bundles it up with all the others as part of an APK build. It goes in, but is not loaded by Qt at runtime.

So i look into how the existing qt image formats work;

turns out, rather than being in a subdirectory, they are named according to this pattern;

`libplugins_imageformats_libqapng.so`

So i rename `libqapng.so` to the above and put that into `libs`. Nice try, but it didn't work.

After a lot of head scratching, i discover there's a secret *resource* array that connects the logical location of plugins to the physical file names;

This lives in;

`res/values/libs.xml`

and looks like this:

```
<array name="bundled_in_lib">
        ...
    <item>libplugins_imageformats_libqgif.so:plugins/imageformats/libqgif.so</item>
    <item>libplugins_imageformats_libqicns.so:plugins/imageformats/libqicns.so</item>
    <item>libplugins_imageformats_libqico.so:plugins/imageformats/libqico.so</item>
    <item>libplugins_imageformats_libqjpeg.so:plugins/imageformats/libqjpeg.so</item>
    <item>libplugins_imageformats_libqsvg.so:plugins/imageformats/libqsvg.so</item>
    <item>libplugins_imageformats_libqtga.so:plugins/imageformats/libqtga.so</item>
    <item>libplugins_imageformats_libqtiff.so:plugins/imageformats/libqtiff.so</item>
    <item>libplugins_imageformats_libqwbmp.so:plugins/imageformats/libqwbmp.so</item>
    <item>libplugins_imageformats_libqwebp.so:plugins/imageformats/libqwebp.so</item>
    ....
```

So, i just need to get my new plugin into that list.

Sure enough, if i **HACK** it in, it works! but how to add my plugin to this list properly as part of the build?

[this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/deployment-android.html) page on Qt Android deployment mentions a thing called `bundled_in_lib`, which is indeed what i need. But it unfortunately does not explain how to change this or to add to it.

I'm thinking there might be a secret magic spell i can add to my `qmake` `.pro` file to affect this `bundled_in_lib` resource.

How to do it? or is there a better way that I've not yet seen. There doesn't seem to be much about explaining these details for Android.

On a final note, an alternative might be to manually load the plugin in `main.cpp`. I've tried this and it doesn't work. Perhaps, they need to be loaded by the Qt image format plugin loader rather than just *loaded* at all. Maybe there's a way to do this. not sure?

using Qt5.9.1

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Following @Felix answer, `ANDROID_EXTRA_PLUGINS` is correct, but how it works is a bit strange.

Following a discussion on the lack of doc for this feature [here](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-60022), and some trial and error, i found that;

`ANDROID_EXTRA_PLUGINS` must specify a *directory*, not a file. So you point to a plugins directory of your own. Things below this directory (including subdirectories) get mangled as in my original question and explained below.

So, for my plugin `libqapng.so`, i have:

`ANDROID_EXTRA_PLUGINS += <some path>/plugins`

and my android plugin building .pro puts the output in;

`<some path again>/plugins/imageformats/libqapng.so`

The `.so` lib, then winds up mangled in (eg. for arm);

`android-build/libs/armeabi-v7a/libplugins_imageformats_libqapng.so`

and the resources get the entry;

`android-build/res/values/libs.xml`

```
    <array name="bundled_in_lib">
    ...
<item>libplugins_imageformats_libqapng.so:plugins/imageformats/libqapng.so</item>
</array>
```

as required.

Thanks to @Felix for almost the answer, but i thought I'd write up the extra details here for the benefit of others.

Comment: @Felix, thanks for this! But none of your suggestions worked, but you were on the right track. I've posted an answer below after following up your tips and some more investigation. cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is on the same site, a little lower on the page: [Android-specific qmake Variables](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/deployment-android.html#android-specific-qmake-variables)

The one you are looking for is most likely `ANDROID_EXTRA_PLUGINS`. There is no usage example, so you will have to try out in wich format to add the plugin here.

My suggestions would be:

```
ANDROID_EXTRA_PLUGINS += imageformats/qapng
```

or

```
ANDROID_EXTRA_PLUGINS += plugins/imageformats/libqapng.so
```

... something like that. This should take care of all the renaming stuff etc. as well.

EDIT:
Its also very possible you need to enter the absolute path, i.e.

```
ANDROID_EXTRA_PLUGINS += $$[QT_INSTALL_PLUGINS]/imageformats/libqapng.so
```

or in whichever path you keep the plugin