# How to include a specific plugin or library in pro file while using ANDROID_DEPLOYMENT_DEPENDENCIES?

Tags: android, qt, qmake

I use Fluid qml library/plugin.

I installed the library using qmake and make, 
its installation path is in *Qt/5.11.0/android_armv7/qml*.

Find source tree is [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/KxHX3d7hNR/).

There is a per-project installation example in it. I tried to modify its pro file to reduce APK size. Here is the pro file [here](https://github.com/lirios/fluid/blob/develop/examples/perproject/minimalqmake/src/src.pro).

I couldn't include the plugin in pro file while using ANDROID_DEPLOYMENT_DEPENDENCIES. This is what I [tested](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/JmzSSK5K5w/).

**Getting Error:**

`W/libsrc.so( 4200): (null):0 ((null)): QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
W/libsrc.so( 4200): (null):0 ((null)): qrc:/main.qml:4 plugin cannot be loaded for module "Fluid.Controls": Cannot load library /data/data/org.qtproject.example.src/qt-reserved-files/qml/Fluid/Controls/libfluidcontrolsplugin.so: (dlopen failed: could not load library "libQt5Svg.so" needed by "libfluidcontrolsplugin.so"; caused by library "libQt5Svg.so" not found) W/libsrc.so( 4200):`

**Question:**

How to include a specific plugin or library in pro file while using _ANDROID_DEPLOYMENT_DEPENDENCIES?

Comment: Have a look at this question/answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47061829/how-to-deploy-qt-imageformats-plugins-on-android/47072136#47072136

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deploy Qt imageformats plugins on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47061829/how-to-deploy-qt-imageformats-plugins-on-android)

Comment: Thanks for answer. I tried the solution but this failed. It gave error: W/libfluid_deneme_optimized.so(24072): (null):0 ((null)): qrc:/main.qml:2 module "Fluid.Controls" plugin "fluidcontrolsplugin" not found

Comment: Fluid *.so files are in [android-build/libs/armeabi-v7a/](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/2SkMhJ9CnQ/)  and [this](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/PfKPDynZ4N/) is pro file. I also tried many combinations, like replacing it with ANDROID_EXTRA_LIBS. It always fails. Per project installation example works well without installing plugins. But it is apk size is too big, so I try to reduce it using ANDROID_DEPLOYMENT_DEPENDENCIES. There is also hello world example about it [here](https://github.com/edips/Minimal_QML_Android).

Comment: when the files are in the build folder, have they been properly renamed? i.e. `libqml_<module_path>_<so_name>.so` or `libplugins_<type>_<so_name>.so`

Comment: Also, make shure all the `*.qml` files are place in the asset folder in `android-build/assets/--Added-by-androiddeployqt--/qml/`

Comment: No I didn't renamed them. Fluid *.so files start with "libFluid". Another plugins start with libqml or libplugin. Maybe the problem is about this. I looked in system data folder of rooted Android device. There are Fluid Qml libs in qml folder and there are Material design, QQC2 QML files in it.

Comment: I will compare asset folder of APK files between working Fluid example and edited example. I will report differences here.

Comment: Felix thanks for the idea, I solved it now. I looked asset folder, and I realized plugin names are different from working example's plugin names. It wasn't about ANDROID_EXTRA_LIBS or ANDROID_EXTRA_PLUGINS.

Comment: Just as sidenode: When using `ANDROID_EXTRA_PLUGINS` the renaming is done automatically, so you don't have to take care of it, as long as the plugins are in the correct location

Comment: When I tried ANDROID_EXTRA_PLUGINS Fluid plugin names were different, it started with "Fluid" instead of "libplugins_<type>_<so_name>.so" or "libqml_<module_path>_<so_name>.so". So I deleted it and included *.so and other files in ANDROID_DEPLOYMENT_DEPENDENCIES. It worked.

Answer (score 1):

I assumed including qmldir, *.so files and *.qmltypes files will include QML files automatically. It didn't work. I edited the pro file again. Then I included required Fluid QML files seperately, it worked! [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/j77Jfd8Gm3/) is the pro file. The APK size reduced from 47MB to 37MB using *ANDROID_DEPLOYMENT_DEPENDENCIES*.